# How to get first values of arrays which are nested another array

Tags: arrays, swift

i'm getting the json from api request and getting all the values in it with id "images" and storing them in an array.
These images are of an ID and these ID's can have mutliple images, single image or no image.

I need to get the first image of all the ID's and show in a table view containing an image view and name.

The size of imagesArray depends on the number of ID's. so i'm loading the table view dynamically after getting the count of ID's. 
Then getting names into nameArray and loading it too but when i'm getting images into imagesArray, the imagesArray is a nested array.

i should get the first image of each ID's in imagesArray.

imagesArray is as follows

```
(
"<null>",
"<null>",
    (
    "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564662590/sfp9qw3rw8zmclhqiuci.jpg"
),
    (
    "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564663071/lop5xsjlb0tvubif6bgu.jpg"
),
    (
    "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564233754/nwainie3gw3vr5fpvgu2.jpg",
    "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564059202/re5aobbpzxmwoxpejjmc.jpg"
),
    (
    "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563893235/fdreobisu5jbymsehpdl.jpg",
    "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563893235/yxewb2taeyu663tb2mdd.jpg",
    "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563893237/hmho0qzcrvaqnvv4ms8u.jpg"
),
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
    (
    "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564731394/eezvfo32ka8ycowqwbdm.jpg"
),
    (
    "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564728682/odvnyid8jjvej8nixxgh.jpg",
    "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564728671/uejymrxidxxucgnkf0rs.jpg"
),
    (
    "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564663236/vvwz58nkqor26utlksbu.jpg",
    "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564663246/kfjav6izqpneo7zqzkrf.jpg"
),
"<null>",
"<null>",
    (
    "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564662222/gvw33j5fq9ly1fevmjez.jpg"
),
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
    (
    "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564663589/fxiqilfhthbdeqcppc4i.jpg"
),
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
    (
    "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563952137/zoqkfhqkwscholrixqkh.jpg",
    "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563958957/cw7odleffnsb4vh1ztgf.jpg",
    "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563958974/hwkg806ty1egdcqvftyp.jpg"
),
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
    (
    "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564058578/xpc09cz1msadanjmdl2d.jpg"
),
"<null>",
"<null>",
"<null>",
    (
    "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563959155/s5t0gilg93stk1c7ocac.jpg"
),
    (
    "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564663516/djudadgmvgn5piboo44m.jpg"
)
```

when i tried getting the images

["dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564662590/sfp9qw3rw8zmclhqiuci.jpg", "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564663071/lop5xsjlb0tvubif6bgu.jpg", "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564233754/nwainie3gw3vr5fpvgu2.jpg", "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563893235/fdreobisu5jbymsehpdl.jpg", "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564731394/eezvfo32ka8ycowqwbdm.jpg", "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564728682/odvnyid8jjvej8nixxgh.jpg", "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564663236/vvwz58nkqor26utlksbu.jpg", "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564662222/gvw33j5fq9ly1fevmjez.jpg", "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564663589/fxiqilfhthbdeqcppc4i.jpg", "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563952137/zoqkfhqkwscholrixqkh.jpg", "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564058578/xpc09cz1msadanjmdl2d.jpg", "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563959155/s5t0gilg93stk1c7ocac.jpg", "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1564663516/djudadgmvgn5piboo44m.jpg"]

got this. This doesn't include null arrays. I want "null" to be added in the output array of first images of all ID's

Answer (score 1):

If the `imagesArray` contains `"<null>"` as `String` values and `arrays` of `String`, i.e. if the `imagesArray` looks like,

```
    let imagesArray: [Any] = [
        [
            "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563893235/fdreobisu5jbymsehpdl.jpg",
            "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563893235/yxewb2taeyu663tb2mdd.jpg",
            "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563893237/hmho0qzcrvaqnvv4ms8u.jpg"
        ],
        "<null>",
        "<null>",
        [
            "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563893236/fdreobisu5jajdsehpdl.jpg",
            "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563893257/yxewb2tqwdu663tb2mdd.jpg"
        ]
    ]
```

You can get the resultant array using **`compactMap(_:)`** like so,

```
    let result = imagesArray.compactMap { (value) -> String? in
        if let arr = value as? [String] {
            return arr.first
        }
        return value as? String
    }
    print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[
  "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563893235/fdreobisu5jbymsehpdl.jpg",
  "<null>",
  "<null>",
  "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563893236/fdreobisu5jajdsehpdl.jpg"
]
```

Comment: I don't think that null values are strings in the original data, the posted snippet looks like a `debugDescription`from the logs.

Comment: @Alladinian Well that depends upon what response OP is getting.

Comment: the solution you have given is correct and i too know this. But it is skipping empty arrays. i want empty arrays also to be added

Comment: Didn't get you. Kindly clarify the solution you're expecting. The answer I gave is the solution for the output you added in the question.

Comment: the array consists of array of images for each ID. Each ID can have multiple images or no images. When an ID have images we can get the first image of the ID but if an ID has no images it is skipping. Before posting question here only i know the answer you have given. I want to get first image of each ID and if the ID have no images it should return null but it is skipping

Comment: Hi PGDev,
Edited my question. Please have a look and help me solve this 
TIA

Comment: `"<null>"` is a string and not an array. Also, in the array you added, there are not Ids there.

Comment: Add the expected output.

Comment: Also, add the json that you're using to get the array of images.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that your imagesArray is this:

```
let imagesArray = [
    [
        "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563893235/fdreobisu5jbymsehpdl.jpg",
        "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563893235/yxewb2taeyu663tb2mdd.jpg",
        "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563893237/hmho0qzcrvaqnvv4ms8u.jpg"
    ],
    nil,
    nil,
    [
        "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563893236/fdreobisu5jajdsehpdl.jpg",
        "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563893257/yxewb2tqwdu663tb2mdd.jpg"
    ],
]
```

then, all you have to do is try to get the first element of the non-nil lists with something like this:

```
let result = imagesArray.compactMap({ $0?.first })
```

which will give you

> ["dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563893235/fdreobisu5jbymsehpdl.jpg", "dmnrvmvaa/image/upload/v1563893236/fdreobisu5jajdsehpdl.jpg"]

---

**Note**: In case you want to include `nil` elements you could use `map` instead of `compactMap` which would result to a list of optional strings `[String?]`